# Perform counting for number of occurrence in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, window-functions, unpivot

Is it common and convenient for SQL to perform such data manipulation, capturing only results in columns satisfying the conditions, and perform counting for number of occurrence? How to write SQL code to generate the desired output (if feasible).

Name is presented only when the conditions (Cond1 to Cond5) are yes.

Desired Input

```
ID Cond1 Cond2 Cond3 Cond4 Cond5 Name1   Name2   Name3   Name4    Name5
1  No    Yes   No    No    Yes   (null)  Result1 n/a     (null)   Result2
2  Yes   No    Yes   No    Yes   Result3 n/a     Result4 (null)   Result5
```

Desired Output

```
ID Counting Name
1  1        Result1
1  2        Result2
2  1        Result3
2  2        Result4
2  3        Result5
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with `union all` and `row_number()`:

```
select id,  row_number() over(partition by id order by seq) couting, name
from (
    select id, name1 name, 1 seq from mytable where cond1 = 'Yes'
    union all select id, name2, 2 from mytable where cond2 = 'Yes'
    union all select id, name3, 3 from mytable where cond3 = 'Yes'
    union all select id, name4, 4 from mytable where cond4 = 'Yes'
    union all select id, name5, 5 from mytable where cond5 = 'Yes'
) x
order by id, rn
```

Comment: Nice & clean (as opposed to my *monster query*).

Comment: @Littlefoot Yes, its a short query but it will need one table/index scan for each `SELECT` in the inner query so it may be inefficient. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b395caf3ba9c56b4170f4a2160ce26ba)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UNPIVOT` with pairs of columns and then filter on the `Yes` rows and use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to get the incremental index of the result:

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value ) AS "COUNT",
       name
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT  ( ( cond, name ) FOR value IN (
    ( Cond1, Name1 ) AS 'V1',
    ( Cond2, Name2 ) AS 'V2',
    ( Cond3, Name3 ) AS 'V3',
    ( Cond4, Name4 ) AS 'V4',
    ( Cond5, Name5 ) AS 'V5'
  ) )
WHERE cond = 'Yes'
```

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  ID    NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  Cond1 VARCHAR2(3) CHECK ( Cond1 IN ( 'Yes', 'No' ) ),
  Cond2 VARCHAR2(3) CHECK ( Cond2 IN ( 'Yes', 'No' ) ),
  Cond3 VARCHAR2(3) CHECK ( Cond3 IN ( 'Yes', 'No' ) ),
  Cond4 VARCHAR2(3) CHECK ( Cond4 IN ( 'Yes', 'No' ) ),
  Cond5 VARCHAR2(3) CHECK ( Cond5 IN ( 'Yes', 'No' ) ),
  Name1 VARCHAR2(10),
  Name2 VARCHAR2(10),
  Name3 VARCHAR2(10),
  Name4 VARCHAR2(10),
  Name5 VARCHAR2(10),
  CHECK ( ( Cond1 = 'Yes' AND Name1 IS NOT NULL ) OR ( Cond1 = 'No' AND ( Name1 IS NULL OR Name1 = 'n/a' ) ) ),
  CHECK ( ( Cond2 = 'Yes' AND Name2 IS NOT NULL ) OR ( Cond2 = 'No' AND ( Name2 IS NULL OR Name2 = 'n/a' ) ) ),
  CHECK ( ( Cond3 = 'Yes' AND Name3 IS NOT NULL ) OR ( Cond3 = 'No' AND ( Name3 IS NULL OR Name3 = 'n/a' ) ) ),
  CHECK ( ( Cond4 = 'Yes' AND Name4 IS NOT NULL ) OR ( Cond4 = 'No' AND ( Name4 IS NULL OR Name4 = 'n/a' ) ) ),
  CHECK ( ( Cond5 = 'Yes' AND Name5 IS NOT NULL ) OR ( Cond5 = 'No' AND ( Name5 IS NULL OR Name5 = 'n/a' ) ) )
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( ID, Cond1, Cond2, Cond3, Cond4, Cond5, Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Name5 )
SELECT 1, 'No',  'Yes', 'No',  'No', 'Yes', null,      'Result1', 'n/a',     null, 'Result2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Yes', 'No',  'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Result3', 'n/a',     'Result4', null, 'Result5' FROM DUAL;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | COUNT | NAME   
> -: | ----: | :------
>  1 |     1 | Result1
>  1 |     2 | Result2
>  2 |     1 | Result3
>  2 |     2 | Result4
>  2 |     3 | Result5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e090834316366a3e3018d9100caba789)*

Comment: Question 1: PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value, should it be order by "name" (instead of order by "value"?)
Question 2: Can I have multiple UNPIVOT within a single SQL query, assuming I have Cond_GROUP2 and Name_GROUP2 in the same table?
Thank you.

Comment: @TonyChan That depends on how you want to order your `COUNT` values. `ORDER BY value` will give an incrementing count in the order they appear in the columns; whereas `ORDER BY name` will give an incrementing count in order of the  strings in the `name` column. For your example data the output will be identical as `Result1`/`Result2` is in the same order whether you compare the values alphabetically or the position in the columns but if you were to swap them in the table then the two queries would give a different output. I can't tell you which is valid as it's your data and your output.

Comment: @TonyChan You can have multiple `UNPIVOT` clauses in a single SQL statement; however I don't follow what you are trying to achieve and its beyond the scope of this question. If you want to extend the question then give it a go trying to find a solution yourself from the documentation and if you can't manage it then ask a new question with the issues you are having.

Comment: Thank you. For question 1, ORDER BY value generate correct result. ORDER BY name actually mess up the order. For question 2, I resolved by using your queries multiple times and join them by the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONNECT BY LEVEL` for achieving the desired result as following:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LVL) AS "Counting",
    NAME_   AS "Name"
FROM
    (SELECT
            T.ID,
            DECODE(LVL, 1, COND1, 2, COND2, 3, COND3, 4, COND4, 5, COND5) AS COND,
            DECODE(LVL, 1, NAME1, 2, NAME2, 3, NAME3, 4, NAME4, 5, NAME5) AS NAME_,
            LVL   AS LVL
        FROM
            YOUR_TABLE T join 
       (Select level as lvl from dual CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= 5) on (1=1)
     )
WHERE COND = 'Yes';
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hm, I tried it - returns 39 rows, which doesn't look like *desired result*.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
SQL> with
  2  test (id, cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4, cond5, name1, name2, name3, name4, name5) as
  3    -- your sample data
  4    (select 1, 'no' , 'yes', 'no' , 'no', 'yes', null     , 'result1', 'n/a'    , null, 'result2' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'yes', 'no' , 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'result3', 'n/a'    , 'result4', null, 'result5' from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    -- values whose COND column is 'yes'
  9    (select id,
 10       decode(cond1, 'yes', name1) n1,
 11       decode(cond2, 'yes', name2) n2,
 12       decode(cond3, 'yes', name3) n3,
 13       decode(cond4, 'yes', name4) n4,
 14       decode(cond5, 'yes', name5) n5
 15     from test
 16    ),
 17  up as
 18    -- unpivot data
 19    (select *
 20     from temp
 21     unpivot (c_name for pc in (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5))
 22    )
 23    -- final result
 24  select id,
 25         row_number() over (partition by id order by c_name) counting,
 26         c_name as name
 27  from up
 28  order by id;

        ID   COUNTING NAME
---------- ---------- -------
         1          1 result1
         1          2 result2
         2          1 result3
         2          2 result4
         2          3 result5

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using UNPIVOT.

```
create table mytab(id number, 
                   cond1 varchar2(3), 
                   cond2 varchar2(3), 
                   cond3 varchar2(3), 
                   cond4 varchar2(3), 
                   cond5 varchar2(3), 
                   Name1 varchar2(7),
                   Name2 varchar2(7), 
                   Name3 varchar2(7), 
                   Name4 varchar2(7), 
                   Name5 varchar2(7));

insert into mytab values(1,'No','Yes','No','No','Yes',null,'Result1','n/a',null,'Result2');

insert into mytab values(2,'Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','Result3','n/a','Result4',null,'Result5');

commit;

select * from mytab;
```

Output:

```
ID COND1 COND2 COND3 COND4 COND5 NAME1   NAME2   NAME3   NAME4    NAME5
1  No    Yes   No    No    Yes   (null)  Result1 n/a     (null)   Result2
2  Yes   No    Yes   No    Yes   Result3 n/a     Result4 (null)   Result5
```

UNPIVOT based solution.

```
with ns as (
select id,
       n,
       names 
  from mytab
unpivot(names for n in (name1 as 'n1', 
                        name2 as 'n2', 
                        name3 as 'n3',
                        name4 as 'n4',
                        name5 as 'n5'))),
cs as (
select id,
       n,
       condns 
  from mytab
unpivot(condns for n in (cond1 as 'n1', 
                         cond2 as 'n2', 
                         cond3 as 'n3',
                         cond4 as 'n4', 
                         cond5 as 'n5')))
select ns.id, 
       row_number() over(partition by ns.id order by ns.n) counting, 
       ns.names 
  from ns inner join cs
    on ns.id = cs.id 
   and ns.n = cs.n 
   and cs.condns = 'Yes'
 order by 1,2;
```

Output:

```
ID COUNTING NAMES
1  1        Result1
1  2        Result2
2  1        Result3
2  2        Result4
2  3        Result5
```